# FormControl hide part of value

Tags: javascript, html, angular, web

I have a parent component with a FormGroup containing several FormControls. This FormGroup also contains a custom child component which additionally adds controls to its parents FormGroup. Therefore, the child component get the formControl as input.

When the form is submitted, I'd like to add a country prefix to the child components FormControls value. Thus, the value should be saved to db with the prefix, but shown to the user without.

The problem: The child component doesn't know about the submit button. So I can't simply add the prefix when the form is submitted. And I cannot add the prefix when the user changes the value because the user would obviously see this "manipulation". And I MUST add this prefix in the child component.

**My question is:** Is there a way to hide a part of the FormControls value from the user? Something like pipe or a "middleware"-function I could add to the FormControl to decide, what to show to the user?

```
// CHILD COMPONENT
@Component({
    selector: 'app-my-comp',
    template: '<input [formControl]="inputField">'
})

export class MyComp {
    @Input() someFormGroup: FormGroup;
    inputField: AbstractControl;

    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
        this.inputField = formBuilder.control("", Validators.required);
        this.someFormGroup.addControl(this.inputField);

        //Here I'd like to add a prefix to the formControls value
        this.inputField.setValue("ABC"); //but the user would see this
        //what I really would like to do:
        this.inputField.setHiddenPrefix("ABC");

    }
}
```

The component is used in this component:

```
// PARENT COMPONENT
@Component({
    selector: 'app-parent-comp',
    template: '<form [formGroup]="someFormGroup">
                   <input [formControl]="someInputField"'
                   <app-my-comp [someFormGroup]="someFormGroup"></app-my-comp>
               </form>
})

export class MyComp {
    someFormGroup: FormGroup;
    someInputField: AbstractControl;

    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You could just add an extra form element with `hidden` tag? It won't be directly attached to anything, but you can work with it after form submission.

Comment: But the parent component MUST not know about the child implementation, because the child will have different implementations per client, so the child must care about this itself. And the submit button is in the parent component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not really solve this, but found an acceptable workaround.

Just creating an Observable in the parent and pass it to the client. This way the parent can inform the child, when the submit button is pressed.

If someone needs the code, just comment.

Comment: I need the code, please